# How to run a jar with lib?

Tags: java, jar, lib

I have this jar file 'domain-directory-configurator-cli-3.1.3000.0.0.0.jar' that doesn't contain dependancies

I have also this file 'domain-directory-configurator-cli-3.1.3000.0.0.0-lib.zip'

I want to run the jar file and my application using the libs.

What is the current syntax?

I tried

```
java -cp 3.1.3000.0.0.0/domain-directory-configurator-cli-3.1.3000.0.0.0.jar com.imperva.itp.directory.configurator.cli.MainClass
```

but I keep getting the exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

so how do I refer the jar to work with the lib file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the maven plugin maven-assembly-plugin

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add code from the code to your post ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming domain-directory-configurator-cli-3.1.3000.0.0.0-lib.zip does contain a number of jar files, you would have to extract themand list them one by one on the classpath.

More user friendly would be to have an executable jar where the main class is already mentioned in the manifest. Note you can configure the classpath in the manifest as well,so for a uer it could be sufficient to run `java -jar domain-directory-configurator-cli-3.1.3000.0.0.0.jar` and both the main class and the classpath are taken from the manifest.

In case you are using Maven, the below combination can help. It downloads all dependencies into the lib directory and configures both the main class and the classpath into the project's jar file.

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
        <manifest>
                        <addDefaultEntries>true</addDefaultEntries>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.imperva.itp.directory.configurator.cli.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Build-Date>$(enf.BUILD_DATE)</Build-Date>
                        <Build-Date-Formatted>$(enf.BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED)</Build-Date-Formatted>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Finally, when distributing your application do not forget to deliver not only your jar but also the lib directory with content.